# How can I get Resharper to run tests in debug, when I get debug is "Inconclusive: Test not run"

Tags: c#, resharper, mstest, resharper-2017

How can I get Resharper to run tests in debug, when I get debug is "Inconclusive: Test not run"

Running any MsTest test in Resharper test runner is Ok, but if I try to debug, the R# test runner just displays `Inconclusive: Test not run`

This happens even with a simple test, e.g.

```
[TestClass]
public class BasicTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Placeholder()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(1, 1);
    }
}
```

But the build-in test runner in Visual Studio works for both just running and for debug

**Additional info:**
It appears to be only happening in my VS 2017 preview instance !

**Additional info:**
It also appears to be happening in my VS 2017 with the recent Update 3 !

Comment: If you are using R# 2017.1.3 release build, it does not support .NET core 2.0 preview (automatically installed with VS2017 preview) - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-464754. Try installing R# 2017.2 EAP build https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin Nope not using any .NET Core

Comment: Just reproduced the issue you'd mentioned for MSTest and VS2017 Preview, updated https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465541 request accordingly.

Comment: @AlexanderKurakin Excellent, well at least it's not something I'm doing ... Bummer, just saw your comment ... Happens in R# 2017.2 EAP builds as well

Comment: Questions on SO should be phrased as questions :)

Comment: @MattKerr "As you wish"  :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As of R# 2017.2 official build (Aug 24,2017), this should work again.

Answer (score 16):

The answer, at least so far, is to install the R# 2017.2 EAP **13** ...

Yes, the 13, not the 12

Comment: Here is a link to EAP13, since it doesn't appear on their official download list yet: http://download.jetbrains.com/resharper/JetBrains.ReSharperUltimate.2017.2.EAP13.exe

Comment: installing the latest using "Check for Updates" worked for me. Went from 2017.1.3 to 2017.2 built Aug 24 2017.

Comment: @wonser, I think you should consider moving your comment to an answer. That's what solved it for me.