# Resharper xUnit tests not working after installing .NET Core 2.0

Tags: .net-core, resharper, xunit

Right after installing .NET Core SDK 2.0, all tests a solution that targets the previous version of .NET Core fail to be discovered by Resharper.

Also, when I add them manually to the session and attempt to run them, I get an "Inconclusive: Test not run":

[image]

Also, there's these exceptions along with the previous message:
[image]

If I uninstall .NET Core SDK 2.0, everything works as expected. No issues at all. Tried both x86 and x64 versions, same results.

[image]

All projects in the solution target .NET Core 1.1.

[image]

Running tests from Test Explorer still works just fine.

[image]

Any ideas on how to solve this? Could it be a Resharper bug?

Comment: are you using [EAP](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/) version?

Comment: Just the regular version. I'm using R# Ultimate 2017.1.3, but it's not EAP.

Comment: possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221086/how-can-i-get-resharper-to-run-tests-in-debug-when-i-get-debug-is-inconclusive)

Comment: If you want to use EAP, you can track the bug [link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-465541)
If not, just wait for full release (will contain the fix)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems we need to wait for a Resharper update (I've encountered exactly the same error).

Meanwhile, you can run your tests from the Visual Studio runner - it seems to be working fine.

*EDIT:*

You can also try installing the early version of the Resharper 2017.2 (https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/eap/) if you feel adventurous ;) I've just checked and it works fine (as of EAP 2017.2 12) with nUnit, xUnit and MSTest tests.

Answer (score 0):

I had this come up with Resharper 2018.1 using Visual Studio 2017 Preview (15.7.27617.1) and by chance I took out the underscore from one of my test classes and happened to rerun the tests and they worked!

So if anyone's still having this problem, try getting rid of underscores in your test class names if you have any.